# Using company wifi for inappropriate sites

Tags: wifi, internet

I was using my company's Wifi while I was trying to search inappropriate things. But some pages were blocked. I stopped when I read the block pages saying that "company's name has blocked this site" or something similar. Will this alarm on their computers?

Comment: I would be surprised if this action *wasn't* logged somewhere.

Comment: But most likely, nobody cares. There are thousands of "blocks" every day even in a mid-sized company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all traffic that goes through their internet (and blocks) will be *logged*.

What will trigger an *alarm* is something only your IT department can tell you. Every company (and IT dept) is different). In my company, you would have HR approaching you very soon...

Comment: Your company HR department must be quite bored if they bother people for every single false-positive of their nanny software.

Comment: @Philipp "some pages" is not a single event - plus, this is not a false positive, it happened, and yes, some companies are very, very strict on this sort of thing because it creates a hostile work environment for others

Answer (score 1):

It has been logged because clearly there is a proxy server present.

That doesn't mean it will alarm anything, many companies enforce this kind of blocking just to block the access to inappropriate sites, not to take action against the people who tried to, so in this case the alarms may not be even set because nobody monitors this activity.

There can be alarms set on just certain traffic (e.g. certain URL categories), or all traffic (unlikely if the company has more than 50 people), or if an event occurs a number of times within a time frame, etc.

tl;dr: the event was recorded and can be seen if someone searches for it but will it trigger any controls depends from company to company.